# Blur with ion-range doesn't work Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

Using ionic `ion range` whenever the user `change` the ion range then I ll send it to the server and make some process then send response, but i can't take the data instantaneous .(I tried with `(click)` event it works but not a good solution for my case).

**Template code**

```
 <ion-item >
  <ion-range min="0" max="200" pin="true" [(ngModel)]="distance" color="secondary"  (blur)="onBlurMethod()">
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker" range-left aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="font-size:25px;" range-right aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </ion-range>
</ion-item>
```

**TS file**

```
onBlurMethod() {
     alert("Distance : ", distance);
}
```

Thank you for all.

Answer (score 1):

The `ngModel` data property sets the element's value property and the `ngModelChange` event property listens for changes to the element's value.

**TEMPLATE**

```
<ion-item >
  <ion-range min="0" max="200" pin="true" [(ngModel)]="distance" color="secondary"  (ngModelChange)="Change()">
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker" range-left aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="font-size:25px;" range-right aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </ion-range>
</ion-item>
```

**TS**

```
Change() {
  alert("Dis: ", distance);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and nice explanation , It worked.Regards @mayur